# Defining shared variables in a package - go

Tags: go

I have a package with multiple go files in it, I am looking for best practices to follow when using these variables

```
var print string

type someStruct struct {
  //some vars
}
```

Consider package files has following go files in it

file1.go has a string variable print

file2.go has a struct someStruct

file3.go needs a string variable print

file4.go needs a struct someStruct

should I access/use the variable from file1.go in file3.go or create a new string variable i.e., file3print

same way should I access/use the someStruct from file2.go in file4.go 
or create a new struct i.e., file3SomeStruct

Comment: It doesn't matter if they're in different files, you cannot have two global variables, types, functions, constants, etc with the same name. Compilation will fail, which you would find if you had tried it.

Comment: As to whether you "should" access a variable from another file or create a new one... that depends entirely on whether you want to share the same variable or use separate variables. No one can answer that question for you, it completely depends upon the context, and it has nothing to do with whether they're in different files - you could just as well ask "should two functions in the same file use the same global variable, or different global variables?" and the answer would remain "it depends".

Comment: Thank you Adrian, I am not defining it with same name, like I asked in the question file3print not print i.e., defining a local variable for that go file

Comment: That's what I'm saying - there's no such thing as a "local variable for that go file", only a variable for the *package*, or a variable for a *function*. There is no "file scope" in Go.

Comment: I understand that there is no file scope, and I referred the `local variable` just to understand that variable declared in that file and I know it is accessible to all files in the package, my whole question here is if you do declare a variable in one file and reuse it in a different file of the same package, its hard to track where the variable is modified, so the whole question is what is the best practice here

Comment: lets say variable is declared in file1.go and is used/modified in many files under the same package, it hard to keep track, if each and every other file has their own `differently named` variables, its easier to keep track, so what is the best practice is what I am looking for

Comment: *It depends*. That's not a question anyone can give a generic/universal answer to. If you need to share a variable, share it. If you don't, don't.

Comment: what about tracking if I share it with many files in a single package?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159187/discussion-between-coding-ninja-and-adrian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create file-specific types, nor variables, a la `file3SomeStruct`, just for the sake of avoiding sharing of those identifiers between files, a practice like this seems to me very unreasonable and would most definitely be considered bad practice.

Sharing of identifiers between files is absolutely ok and you can find countless examples of this practice in the standard library.

Just take a look through the [net/http package source files](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/net/http).

If you want, you can think of packages as representing a single-concept, e.g. HTTP, and the package's files representing its sub-concepts, like an HTTP server, HTTP client, or HTTP request. But for the HTTP to be useful its sub-concepts need to be able to interact. (This is not a required standard, some packages may be better off with a different design.)